# Why is there a grey box floating in the upper-left corner of my image and why is code only resizing the grey box and not the image itself?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm embedding some javascript into my Showit website. It is a drag and drop feature to portray a collage/mood board effect. The code is working great, but I'm having trouble resizing the images.

There is a grey box in the upper left corner of the image that is taking on any code changes. For example, right now the width/height is set to 0px, so the grey box is a tiny dot. If I increase it to 50px, it gets larger but the image stays the same size.

I'm assuming there needs to be some parent code adjustments but I'm still fresh with javascript. I'm sharing links below to hopefully help.

Thanks so much in advance!

Here's a link to the code in action
https://denofdreamers.w3spaces.com/saved-from-Tryit-2022-01-15.html

And here is a link to the code so far
https://www.codepile.net/pile/bOVJbwOm

Comment: Please clarify the question. I do see the tiny gray box, what is it you are trying to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you mentioned happens because you set the `width` and `height` of the frame to `0px`. I disabled the classes used via **jquery.ui** to place a frame on the `<img>` element and added a border on the `<img>` element.

```js
$(function() {
  $( "#draggable1" ).draggable();
  $( "#draggable2" ).draggable();
  $( "#draggable3" ).draggable();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
}

.draggableImage{
  padding: 5px;
  border: 5px solid #EEE;
  width: 50%;
}

.draggableContainer{
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha512-aOG0c6nPNzGk+5zjwyJaoRUgCdOrfSDhmMID2u4+OIslr0GjpLKo7Xm0Ao3xmpM4T8AmIouRkqwj1nrdVsLKEQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-uto9mlQzrs59VwILcLiRYeLKPPbS/bT71da/OEBYEwcdNUk8jYIy+D176RYoop1Da+f9mvkYrmj5MCLZWEtQuA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="draggable1" class="draggableContainer">
    <p>
      <img class="draggableImage" src="https://static.showit.co/file/sJcRsatKTmC2WnNTV_hJVA/118367/screen_shot_2022-01-15_at_12_07_17_pm.png">
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="draggable2" class="draggableContainer">
    <p>
      <img class="draggableImage" src="https://static.showit.co/file/_rojEJb2QBytWaRmzMySCg/118367/screen_shot_2022-01-15_at_12_06_58_pm.png">
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="draggable3" class="draggableContainer">
    <p>
      <img class="draggableImage" src="https://static.showit.co/file/_rojEJb2QBytWaRmzMySCg/118367/screen_shot_2022-01-15_at_12_06_58_pm.png">
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the images starting position somewhat overlap? Similar to how they were in my original code? I'm hoping to have maybe 10-15 images so if they continue stacking they'll run off the web page. Thank you!

Comment: @denofdreamers I developed a solution. You can test it.

Comment: Ok almost there! Now when I make the image width 50%, they continue to shrink as they are dragged to the right. They start off the same size, but as soon as I start dragging one it shrinks. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @denofdreamers I updated the code. I hope the problems are fixed.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much! This is something I've wanted to create for a really long time so I really appreciate your help. If I could ask one more thing... how do I specify the div id to remove the border for just one of the photos? There are some png files I want to add and am hoping to not have a border for those!

Comment: @denofdreamers I think ask this issue in another post.

Answer (score 0):

Do the images need to be inside `p` elements?

Tweaking the content and styling to this seems to work.

```
<div id="draggable" class="draggable ui-widget-content ui-draggable" style="position: relative;left: 5px;top: -4px;background: none;width: 167px;height: 100px;">
    <img src="..." style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
</div>
```

Updated so the `img` element inherits the width of the draggable div.